# Changing Field background colour in accordance to value

Tags: reporting-services, colors, background

I am attempting to put rag ratings in accordance with values in `SSRS tables`, on multiple reports and am using the below expressions infill on the `TextBox` Properties

```
=iif(fields!UtilisationSessionDuration.Value > 0.9,"#EBF1DE","#F2DCDB")
```

I have also tried

```
=iif(fields!UtilisationSessionDuration.Value >= 0.90,"#F2DCDB","#EBF1DE")
=iif(fields!UtilisationSessionDuration.Value <= 0.90,"#F2DCDB","#EBF1DE")
```

But the fields don’t seem to always follow the rule. Some work and some don’t. I was wondering if a `Switch` would be more appropriate in this sense. However, it seems to respond in the same way.

```
=SWITCH(Fields! UtilisationSessionDuration.Value <= 10, "Red", Fields! UtilisationSessionDuration.Value >= 20, "Green")
```

Would anybody have any better solutions?

Comment: i would look into why it `don’t seem to always follow the rule` maybe you're grouping.. maybe you're not considering nulls.. your first line should work fine

Comment: you're right I am grouping my table by Session Duration which shows 2 rows, Half day and full day. Having looked at this I have tried numerous other codes but now they are saying that I am omitting a parameter. I'm wondering if it would be better to create a custom code in the background and use a getcolor expression in the field instead?
Only problem is I have never done this before, would you have any suggestions?

Comment: if it's inside a group, you might try `=iif(Sum(fields!UtilisationSessionDuration.Value) > 0.9,"#EBF1DE","#F2DCDB")`

Comment: Thank you, took me a few attempts but yes your correct

Comment: =iif(Avg(fields!UtilisationCaseDuration.Value) > 0.9,"#EBF1DE","#F2DCDB")

Comment: Awesome.. glad you figured it out!